# Why didn’t they X-ray or operate on Spencer Olham?

Tags: impostor

In both the short story and the film adaptation by Dimension Films of *Impostor* by Philip K. Dick, the Veteran’s hospital had advanced holographic imaging technology. Also, [X-ray tomography has been used to locate bullets](https://www.nde-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/Radiography/Introduction/history.htm) since 1896.

Earlier in the movie they played a video of the EDF

> extracting a Centauri U-bomb from a replicant's heart. The bomb was very easy to see. It seems they could have X-rayed the replicant to find the U-bomb in his heart? Or even removed the heart (maintaining life support) to force coalescence (heart transplant procedure)?

It seems the device does in fact coalesce before the trigger point.

Later in the movie this was partially explained, in a conflicting manner:

> Major Hathaway told the ESA that the bomb cannot be X-rayed. He claimed it used advanced nanotechnology to evade modern detection techniques.

This contradicts the vivisection video he played earlier.

If for no better reason than to save man hours and soldiers' lives, why didn’t they just X-ray or operate?

This is a very complex plotline and I'm trying to reconcile it to see if there is some deception on the part of the ESA, or another power.

Comment: it would be helpful to include the name of the short story / film adaptation you're talking about

Comment: yeah - the PKD tag is too broad and Imposter is likely to not have any tags. I've read almost all PKD and did not remember this character's name.